# cannot load such file == rails/cli error when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Traceback   (most recent call last):
    5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.2.1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
    1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue in require'
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
```

I am not so sure what caused this error. Prior to this I ran into an error regarding railties and what I did was to

```
gem uninstall railties

gem install railties
```

I tried bundle install and this didn't change anything. However I bundle exec rails s